# Redis + websocket-rails (using Redis for more than 1 service)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, thin

I'm using redis to store data specific to my application. We want to add websockets to our app. I'm aware that redis is necessary to use the `websocket-rails` gem. But there seems to be a conflict when using redis for anything else. Has anyone had any success using Rails 4, Redis, and the `websocket-rails` gem? It seems that this combination (Rails 4 + Redis + websocket-rails) is not stable b/c of uses with `em-synchrony` gem.

I've tried this combination where my server was `thin` and `unicorn`. Unicorn/puma are not meant to be used with `websocket-rails` it seems.

Open issues are:
https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/231
https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/191

Answer (score 0):

In the Gemfile move gem 'websocket-rails' to the top of the file and it will work after that, no more Boom.